# Was bedeutet "das macht jemandem zu schaffen"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Während sich viele Menschen darüber freuen, dass wieder mehr Leben und Farbe in die Gärten zieht, macht genau das einigen Menschen zu schaffen.

Was bedeutet "macht genau das einigen Menschen zu schaffen"?

Answer (score 2):

Etwas (Nominativ) macht jemandem zu schaffen = something troubles somedbody, something means a problem for somebody, or somebody is sad about something.

https://dict.leo.org/german-english/schaffen
Scroll down a bit to find the right clause.

Da die Frage auf deutsch ist: Wenn etwas jemandem zu schaffen macht, dann hat derjenige ein Problem damit, kann es nicht leiden, ist neidisch darauf, oder betrübt darüber.

Comment: Yep. See https://www.derwesten.de/panorama/vermischtes/verdacht-auf-coronavirus-achtung-diese-symptome-deuten-auf-etwas-ganz-anderes-hin-id228795877.html

Comment: Ah ! Ok. Never had any allergies, so i didn't think of it. But the grammar stays the same and that particular case would be included in the "is a problem" part :-)